# c realloc(): invalid next size

Tags: c, pointers, null, size, realloc

I get this error and searching online hasn't solved it so, here's my code^^:

```
void addSoggetto(char* s)
{
    soggetti_length++;
    if(realloc(soggetti, soggetti_length*sizeof(int))==NULL) 
    {
        printf("Realloc Failed");
        return;
    }
```

Basically I have an array of pointers (`soggetti`) and its length (`soggetti_length`).
Every time this function is ran, I realloc the size to make place for another pointer.
Problem is, exactly the fifth time the function is called, I get:

```
realloc(): invalid next size
```

Do you know how can I do?
I think I can exclude that the memory I realloc is not enough, I tried to increase it and nothing changes.
Oh, and I debugged it with gdb, the function crashes BEFORE returning, so I don't even get something like a NULL return.

Comment: A compilable example would help. Yours fails to declare the variables it uses and contains more `{` than `}`.

Comment: int and pointers are 32 bit, but yes you are right, it's better...though as i said, that's not the solution, even if i allocate 100 bytes to store 4 of them, the error is the same

Comment: sorry pascal, but the code is divided in more files, and the important part is that one...in the second part of the function i allocate an object and store his pointer in the location i just reallocated on the array

Answer (score 9):

Read the manpage for `realloc()`. `realloc()` returns a pointer to the new allocation, it does not change the old pointer you passed as an argument. (It can't, because C uses pass by value, not pass by reference). So the

```
if(realloc(soggetti, soggetti_length*sizeof(int))==NULL)
```

is a memory leak (and wrong). You need something like:

```
if(sogetti = realloc(soggetti, soggetti_length*sizeof(int)))
```

but in this case, an allocation failure will also leak memory. So, to be safe, you can do:

```
void *newpointer;
if(newpointer = realloc(soggetti, soggetti_length*sizeof(int)))
    {
        sogetti = newpointer;
    }
else
    {
        //handle out-of-memory
    }
```

With the rest of your code, we can see the other problem:

```
Soggetto* new = malloc(sizeof(Soggetto));
...
soggetti[soggetti_length-1]= new;
```

You've allocated an `int` worth of memory (`sizeof(int)`) per `sogetto_length`, but you are storing a 64-bit `Sogetto *`. This thrashes the heap by overwriting its metadata in memory (hence the `invalid next size`, the `size` part of a heap data structure was overwritten).

Write

```
void *newpointer;
if(newpointer = realloc(soggetti, soggetti_length*sizeof(Sogetto *))) //here!
    {
        sogetti = newpointer;
    }
else
    {
        //handle out-of-memory
    }
```

To handle this correctly.
To find such bugs, I'd recommend `valgrind`, `address sanitizer`.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. There's an example that does more or less what the OP wants here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/

Comment: i think you just dig the gold man^^ i'm gonna try it right now, but it feels right^^

Comment: @user3578051 what is `sogetti_length`? A global variable? Could you post the modified code, including all relevant variable declarations?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is the modified code, same error as before at the fifth call of realloc:

*soggetti_length is the global variable that define the length of the array

```
void addSoggetto(char* s)
{

soggetti_length++;
void *newpointer;
if(newpointer = realloc(soggetti, soggetti_length*sizeof(int)))
{
    soggetti = newpointer;
printf("%p  ",soggetti);
}
else
{
    printf("REALLOC FAILED");
return;
}
Soggetto* new = malloc(sizeof(Soggetto));


new->codice = s;
new->numero_contatti=0;
new->array_contatti = malloc(0);
soggetti[soggetti_length-1]= new;

}
```

Comment: I just noticed that if i compile with -m32 everything it's ok O.o it's a 64 bit problem...someone can explain it?

Comment: A comment on your original question answers that: You're allocating `int`s, but writing `Sogetto *`s. On a 64-bit system, in a 64-bit process, **pointers are 64 bit**.

Comment: yes i know, i tried that too (i put sizeof(int)*2), still not working, and still not explaining why it crashes on fifth run...well now it's just a curiosity, i can compile in 32 bit

Comment: I've the exaclty same problem and not even using -m32 works